# Getting a message from social network through restful webService

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I've a requirement to get a message posted by a normal user and following a specific discussion going on in private social network(Hum-hub). I'm looking for Java Api used in this 
issue .  basically i need to create rest service to get those messages and display in admin dashboard.
 can, anybody help me in this issue? Thanks  Rajan

Comment: What research have you done on this so far?

Comment: I've gone through the github Humhub sample project, and  found that we should pass these parameter  social network url and particular user id  to get this. the problem is its written is php and used some framework so i could'nt get this. I think its  not enough to get those messages. I tried with these but its not working. if u could help me.